# How do I fix broken dictionary on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, dictionary

Using iPhone 4s. In settings > general > keyboard I have a British keyboard, and no other keyboards. In settings > general > international I have region format set to UK and language set to British English.

Yet many apps seem to ignore that.  EG the stack exchange app will highlight colour but not color; apps highlight programme (eg tv programme not computer program). There's a bunch of -ise / -ize suffixes that get mangled.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the exact name of the keyboard you have showing in settings/general/keyboard?

Comment: @TomGewecke English - British

Comment: Go to settings/general/keyboard/add new keyboard and see if there is another one called English (UK).  If so, activate that one and deactivate English - British and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to settings/general/keyboard/add new keyboard and see if there is one called English (UK). If so, activate that one and deactivate English - British.